# HTTP.call GET method doesn't work on client

Tags: json, get, meteor

I have code like below:

```
var url = "http://www.telize.com/geoip";
HTTP.call("GET", url, function(err, res){
  if (err){
    console.log("HTTP call GET error: "+err);
  } else {
      var respJson = JSON.parse(res.content);
      console.log("HTTP call GET response: "+JSON.stringify(respJson));
  };
});
```

I run the this code on server and client.
On server there is OK, I've got response with information in JSON format.
On client side I've got an error: "Error: network".

What to do to get JSON response on client side?
Whats wrong?

Regards,
DP

Answer (score 2):

First of all, client code is subject to the [Same Origin Policy (SOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). That's why you can't do XHR cross-domain, unless the remote server actually supports [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

On a traditional setup, you get around this by either using JSONP or **your server as proxy**.

On Meteor, you can just create [a method on the server](http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header) that does the request for you. That way, it's the server that's doing the request in behalf of the client code. Meteor [HTTP methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#http) can be called synchronously so you can do a `return`.

```
//On the server
Meteor.methods({
  'remoteGet' : function(url,options){
    return HTTP.get(url,options);
  }
});

//On the client
Meteor.call('remoteGet','http://remoteurl.com/',{
  //...options...
},function(error,response){
  //if an error happened, error argument contains the details
  //if the request succeeded, the response will contain the response of the server request
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy): you cannot do cross-domain AJAX request client-side due to security reasons.

There are several solutions at hand:

- Use a proxy which runs on your own domain.
- JSONP

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your logic in a Meter.methods. (See meteor docs). That it the "meteor" way to make a client-to-server call.